# Migrating custom code from one theme to another

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, migration, field

I have custom code for custom woocommerce fields added to child theme of current theme. Everything works as it should. There are hundred of products already on site with those fields filled. Now I want to switch to another theme. My questions are:

1. Is it safe to just copy custom code to child function of another theme?
2. Is it better to copy it to plugin?

I need all entered values to stay in database and on frontend and without duplicate fields. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both methods are ok…

Comment: T h a n k  Y o u !